Google Vision Product Search
I followed the Vision Product Search tutorial as found on - https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/create-product-set-search-products.
I have successfully imported and indexed a csv of products, but when I run the command to search for products:
curl -X POST 
-H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" 
-H "x-goog-user-project: meenaps" 
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" 
-d @search_request.json 
https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate
I only get a result with an annotation of the image and not matching products.
I have tried re importing and making a new project. According to the tutorial this is the right command to run.Any help would be appreciated
I tried to run a product search on a repository of images which are bangles (jewelery). I have labeled them as apparel-v2, they all have bounding polys which take a 12.5% margin out of the image to focus on the center. They are all good quality iamges on a white background.
